# Probability of a sample belonging to a joint categorical distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, categorical-data

I have a set of $n$ independent random Variables $X_i \sim \text{Cat}_i$ distributed by a joint categorical distributions model $C$. I can easily compute the probability of a random vector $\vec x=(x1,\ldots,x_n)$ being produced by this distribution. The probability of an observation $x$ is $ P(x|C) = \prod_i P(x_i|C_i)$ and the values get very small with increasing $n$.

Therefore, I am interested in some sort of *plausibility function* of an observation $\vec x$ belonging to the distribution. 
Intuitively, I thought that a score function $S(x) = \frac{P(x|C)}{\max_y P(y|C)}$ would meet my requirements–the range of $S(x)\in[0,1]$ and can be interpreted more easily. However, I wonder *what* this would compute. Is my intuition wrong and are there more suitable ways of computing a plausibility of an observation belonging to a joint distribution?

Comment: It's unclear why the value taken by the true PMF (which is known) is problematic. As $n$ increases, the number of possible values of $\mathbf{x}$ increases, so naturally large $n$ implies low probability for the observed vector  $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: I don‘t want the probability of $\vec x$ given the model, but rather  a measure of confidence that $\vec x$ is produced by the distribution. So mapping the most likely $P(\hat x)$ to $1.0$ seems intuitive